# CSS Layout places text right next to it instead of below

Tags: css, text, layout

I have a problem with my CSS layout seen below:

```
#wrapper { 
 width: 80%;
} 

#content { 
 float: left;
 background: #FFFF00;
 height: 350px;
 width: 70%;
 display: inline;
}

#rightcolumn { 
 background: #EBE3CD;
 height: 350px;
 width: 30%;
 height: 250px;
 float: left;
}

#legendcolumn {
 background: #FF00FF;
 height: 100px;
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
}
```

The body of my HTML is as follows:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
   Main Content.
  </div>
  <div id="rightcolumn">
   Right Column.
  </div>
  <div id="legendcolumn">
   Here comes the legend.
  </div>
 </div>

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Unfortunately, the text *lorem ipsum dolor sit amet* is placed next to the layout. However, I would like to place the text right below the layout. How can I achieve this without introducing a new *div* container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The float and inline contents are causing the issue, but you can control that with *The Power of Overflow*:

```
#wrapper 
{  
  width: 80%; 
  overflow: auto;  // overflow + float = magic happy land
}
```

Edit: You can see why display:block and clear:both won't work if you add a `border: 1px solid red;` to `#wrapper`. One of the consequences of float is that the container will collapse to the height of it's non-floating children (zero here). Block and Clear will have zero apparent affect (block would have anyway - divs are natively block) if the element they reference is zero height. Overflow auto overcomes this.

Comment: Thanks annakata. This is the only working solution by now. Neither *display:block* nor *clear:both* helped.

Answer (score 1):

Because your #wrapper is set to only 80% in width, those text element will try to fill the rest 20% of the screen with it. No exact solution without new div, but I think following may workaround:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 20%:
}
```

Comment: My bad! I overlooked the `float:left` for those inside stuff. overflow:auto should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS like:

```
#wrapper { 
 width: 80%;
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Divs are block by default, this shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have `#wrapper` width as 80%? make it 100% instead.